# Is there a Blazor call to copy Model.cs properties to/from page.razor based on property/control names?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I haven't seen anything like this but it seems to me it's doable and Blazor (server side) keeps pleasantly surprising me with cool functionality. So I figure I should ask.

If I have a model (from Entity Frameworks if that is relevant), say User.cs as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; }
    // ...
}
```

And I also have a web page, say signup.razor:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="username">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"><br>
  <label for="username">Email: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email"><br>
  <!-- ... -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Is there some call to go through all input controls in the html file and where the name of any is identical to a property in a passed on model object, set that control's value to the property in the object?

And vice-versa where it reads the model object properties and writes them to the input controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You could try with [EditForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/blazor-improve-how-forms-work/4-take-advantage-power-blazor-forms)

bind the attributes like:

```
<InputDate @bind-name="" @bind-id=" @bind-Value= ></InputDate>
```

Comment: Oh wow - this is perfect. Blazor continues to surprise & impress me. Thanks